# Rounding time up to nearest 6 minute with mySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a `DATETIME` field in mySQL (`fromStamp`) with a valid date/time stamp in it.
I need to be able to round the minutes UP to the next 6 minute interval.  Seconds should be ignored or treated as :00

So, if my DATETIME is `2013-01-31 13:07:17` I need the result to be `2013-01-31 13:12:00`
EXCEPT for times between :00 and :06 and :31 and :36 those need to be rounded **DOWN**.

```
 :00-06 round DOWN to 00
 :07-12 round UP to 12
 :13-18 round UP to 18
 :19-24 round UP to 24
 :24-30 round UP to 30
 :31-36 round DOWN to 30
 :37-42 round UP to 42
 :43-48 round UP to 48
 :49-54 round UP to 54
 :55-00 round UP to 00
```

I found a reasonable way to selectively round down using:

```
SELECT
  fromStamp, 
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ',
         SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(`fromStamp`) DIV 360) * 360))
FROM `table` 
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%i') BETWEEN 0 AND 6 
    OR DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%i') BETWEEN 31 AND 36
);
```

Is there a good way of rounding everything else up to the next 6 minute interval?
(I feel like I'm missing something simple)

**UPDATE**

So I'm going with @mellamokb's solution but his comment regard seconds is right, it does come into play.

A DATETIME of 2013-01-22 12:24:13 rounds UP to 12:30 which is not what is needed so I'll first do:

```
UPDATE table SET fromStamp = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(fromStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i'), ':00');
```

to get rid of the seconds then his query which gets exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You haven't defined your borders very clearly.  For instance, does `06:30` round DOWN to `00:00`, or round UP to `12:00`?  Technically, it is in the range `00-06`, but I think you intended `06` and some seconds to be included in the next range.

Comment: Note to future readers: minute values of '6' and '36' do not get rounded down by the example expressions given. This behavior does not meet the specification. This same behavior occurs in the answer from mellamokb; which we expect, because that answer uses the same expression to do the "rounding" down. The selected algorithm does not meet the spec for all datetime values; some "minutes:seconds" combinations would get rounded to values that diff from the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding up is very similar logic, except you add `1` to shift to the next nearest `6-minute` interval.  I've also subtracted `1` from `TIME_TO_SEC` as a correcting factor, otherwise borderline values such as `06:00` get shifted up the next 6-minute interval, i.e., `12:00`.

```
SEC_TO_TIME( ( (TIME_TO_SEC(`fromStamp`) - 1) DIV 360 + 1) * 360))
                                                      ^^^ add one
```

To combine the two, use a `CASE` statement to control which form of rounding is used per record:

```
SELECT
  fromStamp, 
  CASE WHEN
    DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%i') BETWEEN 0 AND 6 
    OR DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%i') BETWEEN 31 AND 36
  THEN
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ',
         SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(`fromStamp`) DIV 360) * 360))
  ELSE
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ',
         SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(`fromStamp`) - 1) DIV 360 + 1) * 360))
  END
FROM `table`
```

([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9341/2))

Comment: The query in this answer does not round minute values of 6 down to 0, or minute values of 36 down to 30. It "rounds" these to 6 and 36, respectively. (The issue is issue is present in the OP query as well.) This does not return the resultset in the OP specifications. (Heaven help the poor soul who later has to read this and figure out what this expression is supposed to be doing.)

Comment: @spencer7593: Agreed. I voted your answer up, and I do think it's a better answer :)  However, the original question was how to round up instead of rounding down, which is where I started from.  If you deconstruct the query step-by-step it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way to handle this odd type of rounding , based on the criteria provided, would be:

```
 SELECT `fromStamp`
      , DATE_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%Y-%m-%d %H') + INTERVAL
        CASE
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <=  6 THEN  0  -- round DOWN
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 12 THEN 12  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 18 THEN 18  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 24 THEN 24  -- round up
         -- WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 30 THEN 30  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 36 THEN 30  -- round DOWN
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 42 THEN 42  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 48 THEN 48  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') <= 54 THEN 54  -- round up
            WHEN TIME_FORMAT(`fromStamp`,'%i') >= 55 THEN 60  -- round up
        END MINUTE AS rnd_fromStamp
```

That seems the most straightforward way to express what is happening, for future reviewers who look at the statement, and wonder "What the *plastic* is that statement doing to fromStamp?"

There might be slightly faster (more efficient) algorithms, but I don't think any of those are going to be any more elegant, or as easily readable and understood as this.

Answer (score 0):

This i used for rounds up to minute

> SELECT
>   MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(call_duration))  DIV 60 +1)*60))
>   call_duration
>   FROM
>   call_log